# error 405 in rest api with method post

Tags: angular, hibernate, cors, jersey

I have a problem about the method post in my program java rest api. I use as back-end: jersey and hibernate and as front-end: angular. when I consume web service by method post in angular application and test program in web browser, the console browser show an error as:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Non Allowed Method)"

I see a tutorial about this problem and it give me a solution that use a CORS which manages the http method and I understand about the CORS but my problems are:
-how to code this CORS in my java program?
-should I create a class with CORS method?
-where should I call CORS in my program?
Please help me. thank you very much

it's rest api

```
package com.ws.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.ws.dao.DaoFactory;
import com.ws.entity.Personne;
import com.ws.jpa.PersonneJPA;

@Path("/personne")
public class PersonneRest {

    private PersonneJPA jpa_personne;

    public PersonneRest() {
        this.jpa_personne = DaoFactory.getInstance().get_personne();
    }

    /*
     * #########################################################################
     * PROCEDURES
     * #########################################################################
     */

    // Getall
    @Path("/getall")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Personne> getAll() {
        return jpa_personne.findAll();
    }

    // Get par ID
    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Personne getById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        List<Personne> h_personne = jpa_personne.findById(id);
        if (h_personne == null)
            return null;
        return h_personne.get(0);
    }

    // Ajout d'un enregistrement de type Langue
    @Path("/add")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void add(Personne personne) {
        jpa_personne.add(personne);
    }

    // Mise a jour d'un enregistrement de type Langue
    @Path("/update")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void update(Personne personne) {
        jpa_personne.update(personne);
    }

    // Suppression d'un enregistrement de type Langue
    @Path("/delete")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void delete(Personne personne) {
        jpa_personne.delete(personne);
    }
}
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Define the ResourceConfig class -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all the URLs to the Jersey ServletContainer -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle CORS on the server, you should use a [Jersey request/response filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9365). This filter correctly handles both the [CORS Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and the regular CORS request.

If you are using package scanning to register your resources and providers, then the filter should automatically get registered because of the `@Provider` annotation.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
            return;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null
                && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response)
            throws IOException {
        if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, " +
                "Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, CSRF-Token");
        }
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

#### Update

To register the filter, what you want to do is put the package the filter is in into the `param-value` for the `init-param` that tells Jersey to scan those packages for your resources and providers. So if your filter is in `com.ws.util`, then you would do the following

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.ws.rest, com.ws.util</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Notice I just added the package delimited with a comma. You could also switch out the two packages listed for simply `com.ws` The package scanning is recursive, so just listing the parent package, will cause the scanning to reach both `com.ws.rest` *and* `com.ws.util`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. for the moment, it's just a definition of the CorsFilter class but I would like to know how to use it so that the program takes into account this CORS when the rest API executes? please, can you give me an example how to use it with the rest api (com.ws.rest)?

Comment: You just need to register it and it is automatically called for all requests. If you need help registering it, please post your application configuration]

Comment: thank you very much, I just register this class and it's OK

Comment: See my **Update**. This is what you need to do to register the filter.

Comment: Thank you, it's OK. last question. what are the keywords that I type to find optimize my codes? I need to optimize my code because I don't think about optimize codes.